# Populate nested array in mongoose - Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

These are my schemas (Topic is parent and contains a list of 'Thought's):

```
var TopicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, unique: true },
  category: String,
  thoughts: [ThoughtSchema]
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  toObject: {virtuals: true},
  toJSON: {virtuals: true}
});

var ThoughtSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  author: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  votes:[{
    _id:false,
    voter: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    up: Boolean,
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  toObject: {virtuals: true},
  toJSON: {virtuals: true}
});

....
```

I am trying to read the thought's author and change my get Topic api like this:

```
...
  var cursor = Topic.find(query).populate({
    path: 'thoughts',
    populate: {
      path: 'author',
      model: 'User'
    }
  }).sort({popularity : -1, date: -1});

  return cursor.exec()
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
...
```

But the author is null.. i also do not get any error in the console. What is wrong here?

Edit: Actually i do not need the Thought as a schema, it does not have its own collection in database. It will be saved in topics. But in order to use **timestamps** option with thoughts, i needed to extract its contents to a new local schema ThoughtSchema. But i have now defined the contents of thoughtSchema directly in the thoughts array of topics, it still does not work.

Edit2: This is the cursor object just before it is executed. Unfortunately i cannot debug in Webstorm, this is a screenshot from node inspector:

[image]

Comment: @Theodore answer looks correct to me: what's the content of `query`? Do you have any `select` in it?

Comment: i have uploaded a screenshot of cursor object's content just before it is executed

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using [Model.populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate)?

```
Topic.find(query).populate('thoughts')
.sort({popularity : -1, date: -1})
.exec(function(err, docs) {
   // Multiple population per level
  if(err) return callback(err);
  Thought.populate(docs, {
    path: 'thoughts.author',
    model: 'User'
  },
  function(err, populatedDocs) {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    console.log(populatedDocs);
  });
});
```

**UPDATE:**
You can try with [deep populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate) like this:

```
Topic.find(query).populate({
  path: 'thoughts',
  populate: {
    path: 'author',
    model: 'User'
  }
})
.sort({popularity : -1, date: -1})
.exec(function(err, docs) {
  if(err) return callback(err);
  console.log(docs);
});
```

Comment: 'Thought' is not exported. I don't know also how to export multiple schemas... This is the only export line: export default mongoose.model('Topic', TopicSchema);

Comment: You don't need to export it as you are using it as an embedded schema. In that case I confirm @Theodore's answer should work. Did you check your database? Is the reference to `author` saved correctly?

Comment: yes.. the author field has the id of the User. But i somehow could not debug the server side code in webstorm to see how the query looks..  i will try to debug in the following days.
But about the "Thought" schema.. when i use Thought.populate as you suggest, application cannot be compiled.. sth like "Thought is undefined" appears in terminal

Comment: I suggested another option you can try.

Comment: that's exactly what i have written in my question

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Topic.find(query).populate('thoughts')
.sort({popularity : -1, date: -1})
.exec(function(err, docs) {
   // Multiple population per level
  if(err) return callback(err);
  Topic.populate(docs, {
    path: 'thoughts.author',
    model: 'User'
  },
  function(err, populatedDocs) {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    console.log(populatedDocs);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the schemas :

```
var TopicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, unique: true },
  category: String,
  thoughts: [ThoughtSchema]
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  toObject: {virtuals: true},
  toJSON: {virtuals: true}
});

var ThoughtSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  author: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  votes:[{
    _id:false,
    voter: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    up: Boolean,
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  toObject: {virtuals: true},
  toJSON: {virtuals: true}
});
```

Did you try Aggregation Instead of Populate. Aggregate Makes much easier for populating the embedded data using `$lookup`. Try the below code.

**UPDATE**

```
Topic.aggregate([{$unwind: "$thoughts"},{ $lookup: {from: 'users', localField: 'thoughts.author', foreignField: '_id', as: 'thoughts.author'}},{$sort:{{popularity : -1, date: -1}}}],function(err,topics){
 console.log(topics) // `topics` is a cursor.
 // Perform Other operations here.
})
```

**Explanation**:

**$unwind**: Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element.

**$lookup**: The $lookup stage does an equality match between a field from the input documents with a field from the documents of the “joined” collection. The lookup does the population's job.

*$lookup works like*

**from** :  this says from which collection the data needs to be populated.(`users` in this scenario).

**localField** : this is the local field which needs to be populated. (`thoughts.author` in this scenario).

**foreignField** : this is the foreign field present in the collection from which data needs to be populated (`_id` field in `users` collection in this scenario).

**as** : this is the field as what you want to display the joined value as. (this will project thoughts.author's id as thoughts.author document).

Hope this works.

Comment: "Did you try Aggregation Instead of Populate" Sorry.. But aggregate is normally used with "match" instead of "find" as far as i know.. so it is not an alternative to populate but to 'find' i think .. so i dont know how to integrate this to my code.. does aggregate return also a cursor object, which must be executed afterwards? Could you please update my second code in the question and write all the lines?